# Rails API return nested values from nested values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, controller, nested

I have an app where you can download quizzes. Each quiz has multiple questions. Each question has five possible answers. These are my models:

First the **Quiz Model:**

```
class Quiz < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :questions
    has_many :games

    validates_presence_of :title
    validates_presence_of :abstract
    validates_presence_of :category_id

    validates_uniqueness_of :title

end
```

The **Question Model:** (each question belongs to a quiz object)

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :quiz

    has_many :answers
    has_many :game_questions

    validates_presence_of :quiz_id
    validates_presence_of :question

end
```

And lastly the **Answer Model:** (each answer belongs to a question)

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :question

    has_many :game_questions

    validates_presence_of :question_id
    validates_presence_of :answer
    validates_inclusion_of :correct_answer, :in => [true, false]
    validates_presence_of :order

end
```

I want to make a get request to my QuizzesController via this route **/quiz_content/:id** and then become the **quiz** with the corresponding id and **all questions** and for each question **all connected answers**

I already managed to return a quiz with all it's answers:

```
  def quiz_content
    quiz_records = Quiz.where('id = ?', params[:id]).includes(:questions)
    @quiz_records_with_associations = quiz_records.map do |record|
      record.attributes.merge('questions' => record.questions)
    end
    render json: @quiz_records_with_associations
  end
```

Calling this controller return the following JSON-File:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Testquiz",
    "abstract": "Questions for dummies",
    "category_id": 1,
    "download": 0,
    "created_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.511Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.511Z",
    "questions": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "quiz_id": 1,
        "question": "What is 5 + 5?",
        "created_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.561Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.561Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "quiz_id": 1,
        "question": "What's the color of the sky?",
        "created_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.588Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.588Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "quiz_id": 1,
        "question": "How fast can a cheetah run?",
        "created_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.602Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.602Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "quiz_id": 1,
        "question": "How many eyes does a pig have?",
        "created_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.620Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.620Z"
      },      
      {
        "id": 5,
        "quiz_id": 1,
        "question": "How would you rate this quiz?",
        "created_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.611Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-20T17:16:42.611Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My problem now is, that I couldn't figure out how to return all five answers for each question. I hope you can help me with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `Quizz.rb`

```
def as_json
  super(include: { questions: { include: :answers } })
end
```

And

```
def quiz_content
  @quiz = Quiz.includes(questions: :answers).find(params[:id])

  render json: @quiz.as_json
end
```

Comment: Does not work, I get the folllowing error:

undefined method `includes' for #<Quiz:0x00000002074980>
Extracted source (around line #43):

@quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id]).includes(questions: :answers)

Comment: Check the updated answer. You need to change the order of `find` and `includes`

Comment: It works, but I only get the quiz resource... The Server logs show the following database queries:

Processing by QuizzesController#quiz_content as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Quiz Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "quizzes".* FROM "quizzes" WHERE (id = '1')
  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."quiz_id" = 1
  Answer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: and then: 
No serializer found for resource: {"id"=>1, "title"=>"Testquiz", "abstract"=>"Questions for dummies", "category_id"=>1, "download"=>0, "created_at"=>Sat, 20 May 2017 17:16:42 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sat, 20 May 2017 17:16:42 UTC +00:00}
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with Array (0.16ms)

Comment: my Serializer for the Quiz models looks like this:

`class QuizSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :id, :title, :abstract, :category_id, :download
end`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution myself:

```
  def quiz_content
    @quiz = Quiz.where('id = ?', params[:id])
    render json: @quiz, include: ['questions', 'questions.answers']
  end
```

And I had to add the associations in the serializers:

```
class AnswerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

    attributes(:id, :question_id, :answer, :correct_answer, :order)

    belongs_to :question

end


class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

    attributes(:id, :quiz_id, :question)

    belongs_to :quiz
    has_many :answers
    has_many :game_questions

end


class QuizSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

    attributes(:id, :title, :abstract, :category_id, :download)

    has_many :questions

end
```